# Can I select only the text/label from this code and wrap a tag around it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I am dealing with a CMS system here which generated wonderful (not) code.  I cannot change the way the code/content is generated, but I can add my own JavaScript / jQuery code to rewrite the generated content.  I am looking at a form which looks like this ...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            First Name<br><input id="first_name_field" name="first_name" value="" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            State/Province/Region<br><div id="regstatediv_187"><select name="state" id="state_field" class="inputbox"><option value=" ">Select State/Province/Region</option><option value="ALA">Alabama</option>...</select></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have been playing with the html() and text() functions in jQuery and thus far cannot find a way to select only the text "label" and then wrap it and write it back without destroying the form field in the process.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide much support at all for dealing with text nodes in the DOM.  However there are plugins that might be useful, such as [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com). Or you could look at that code for ideas on how to "mine" text from the DOM.

Comment: ... or you could ignore me and use @ShankarSangoli's answer :-)

Comment: @Pointy  I just had to laugh on that last comment :) really!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('table td').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<span class="label" />');//use any markup you want to wrap with
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qMJQa/)**

Comment: Yes we can use a label too. OP can add any markup as per the need. The point is to find those labels through jQuery.

Comment: I get it. Just noted because in the example you might want to show the best practice, but it is not a big thing.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!  I was trying to do too much and parse the text, etc.  Thanks for the help!